# .bashrc at ssh login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash

When I ssh into my ubuntu-box running Hardy 8.04, the environment variables in my `.bashrc` are not set.

If I do a source `.bashrc`, the variables are properly set, and all is well.

How come `.bashrc` isn't run at login?

Comment: How on earth is this "off topic"?

Comment: I'm not strict like this, but my guess is that this belongs in serverfault.com, superuser.com, or askubuntu.com

Comment: @MichaelButler Agreed. Wonder why they don't move it instead of just close it down...

Comment: @Luc - Questions can only be moved within 60 days of being created. This question wasn't closed as off topic until 3 and a half years after it was created. I believe the 60 days rule has something to do with when the question databases are backed up or something... it becomes more difficult to migrate after that backup occurs.

Comment: I thought it was a pretty useful question. Encountered this issue when I had to ssh into machine A, in order to ssh into machine B (only accessible via A's local network). Taught me a practical difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` !

Comment: A great answer is provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332533/393910).

Answer (score 826, accepted):

`.bashrc` is not sourced when you log in using SSH. You need to source it in your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: this should work on any sane distro with Bash, thus all these comments are obsolete :)

Comment: This isn't necessary with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, since `.bashrc` is sourced when you SSH in, by default.

Comment: @orokusaki: I'm running a fresh install of 12.10 and .bashrc is not sourced by default.

Comment: @orokusaki: Correction, it is :)  There was a rogue .bash_profile file which was forcing .profile to be skipped.

Comment: alternately it can be copyed from `/etc/skel/.bash_profile` into your home drive

Comment: Like @LesterPeabody, my .bashrc wasn't being sourced on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server because of a rogue .bash_profile. It was created by the RVM install. I moved the RVM command to .profile and delete .bash_profile. All running fine now.

Comment: See the @loic-wolff answer, the last on this page if you are login by terminal.

Comment: A lot of people say that I **shouldn't** do this because it breaks rsync and the like. The other half says that I should do it because that's what makes it work. So... what is the final solution here...?

Comment: I had to run `chsh -s /bin/bash` in my script as the `vm` hadn't got `bash` setup as the ssh login shell.

Comment: fwiw Debian Jessie/8 already sources `.bashrc` out-of-the-box - but it does it from `.profile`, not `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Debian Jessie did not source my .bashrc but working with .bash_profile. Regarding to this documentation it should read both .bash_profile & .profile in this order (https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: in one line: `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Why is it `. ~/.bashrc` and not `source ~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 109):

I had similar situation like Hobhouse. I wanted to use the command

```
ssh myhost.com 'some_command'
```

where `some_command` exists in `/var/some_location`.

I tried to append `/var/some_location` to the PATH environment variable by editing `$HOME/.bashrc` but that wasn't working. Because per default, `.bashrc` (on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS) exits early due to this piece of code:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Meaning if you want to change the environment for the ssh non-login shell, you should add code above that line.

Comment: Cool tip dewd. I've run into this trap when running scripts from jenkins. I've logged via ssh and it worked. Jenkins logged non-interactively and it failed.

Comment: Why the common solution is to not even set a new path for non-interactive shells is beyond me.  There should be quite a bit above that if statement, for just this reason.  Seems like only the aliases and the initialization of interactive tools should go below that line...

Comment: On other version of Ubuntu the interactive check looks like:
```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. Wish I'd seen this about an hour ago!

Comment: From `man ssh`: " If a command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell." For me on Fedora Core 29 it doesn't call neither .bashrc nor .bash_profile when running commands (and calls them without commands).

Comment: Been searching for how to get around this to deploy my apps easily using a single command. Thanks, dude, I wish I had found this months ago. I even started writing an app to ease my deployment

Answer (score 39):

If ayman's solution doesn't work, try naming your file `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile`. That worked for me.

Comment: Awesome. I lost 15 minutes on this detail.

Comment: i think .profile loads on GUI login. .bash_profile its for terminal logins.

Comment: This also worked for SSH login to a Debian Jessie docker container (using a data only container for persistent storage) - BUT you may also want to check /etc/passwd to check your login shell is /bin/bash & not /bin/sh -------> /bin/dash

Comment: @RazecLuar `.profile` is to be executed by _any_ login shell, regardless of whether said shell intends to spawn a GUI. Your comment totally contradicts the question and this answer, which clearly indicate that `.profile` is invoked on SSHing in - a distinctly non-GUI method.

Answer (score 38):

For an excellent resource on how bash invocation works, what dotfiles do what, and how you should use/configure them, read this:

- [DotFiles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles)

> Now let's take the second-simplest example: an ssh login. This is extremely similar to the text console login, except that instead of using getty and login to handle the initial greeting and password authentication, sshd(8) handles it. sshd in Debian is also linked with PAM, and it will read the /etc/pam.d/ssh file (instead of /etc/pam.d/login). Otherwise, the handling is the same. Once sshd has run through the PAM steps (if applicable to your system), it "execs" bash as a login shell, which causes it to read /etc/profile and then one of .bash_profile or .bash_login or .profile.

Comment: The key passage: "causes it to read /etc/profile and then one of .bash_profile or .bash_login or .profile."

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old issue, but I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.

have two identical servers, one of them source `~/.bashrc` properly, I see colors once I login by ssh, the other was not

both servers had the exact same `~/.bashrc` file

in my case the issue was when I installed golang using one liner on one of these two, it added new file `~/.bash_profile`

that file only had three export path settings, so for some reason when I ssh this file was being source and not `~/.bashrc`

removing `.bash_profile` and only keeping `.bashrc` solved the issue for me, or you can follow @swaz suggestion and keep both files

Answer (score 0):

Similar as @Loïc Wolff  , Added below in my `$HOME/.bash_profile` Ubuntu 16

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        echo "Executed .bash_profile , calling .bashrc"
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```