# Unable to set JAVA_HOME in ssh session (on root user)

Tags: bash, scripting, environment-variables, java-home

I want a ssh session with `root` account and env variable `JAVA_HOME`. I have export `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. When running command,

> ssh -t root@localhost "source /etc/bash.bashrc; echo javahome=\$JAVA_HOME"

the printout in the shell is `javahome=`. But when doing following, I can see `JAVA_HOME` is correctly set.

> ssh root@localhost
>
> source /etc/bash.bashrc
>
> echo javahome=$JAVA_HOME

what could be the possible cause? and in generally, how to have a ssh session with `JAVA_HOME` set. The scripts are run with `bash4` on `ubuntu12.04-64`

PS: I finally put the configuration script into `/root/.profile`, then everything works... which is kinda workaround but not the solution to the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Add the variable definition to `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help: [.bashrc at ssh login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login)
although I am not sure if it is correct that you are using bash.bashrc file when I would expect .bashrc