# how to set rvm ruby as default version for system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

when I do `ruby -v` it shows

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby1.8
* ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

and

```
You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

and when i run `/bin/bash --login` and then run `ruby -v` it shows

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
```

But i dont want to run `/bin/bash --login` command every time. I want my system to set ruby 2.1.0 as default ruby from rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely your login context.  This is because ssh, by default, uses a different launch context than local bash shell.  See here:

[.bashrc at ssh login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login)

You'll need to add the following to .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

If you're using sudo su, etc, to change context, then you'll have to add the -l flag to establish the same context.

This answer is just a guess, it's hard to tell why your particular environment isn't loading, but this is a common cause.

Comment: thanks for that quick reply. can you please tell me how to edit .bash_profile?

Comment: But where is it located in the system?