# Gitlab-ci.yml, SSH and NVM: connect to server via ssh and run nvm use

Tags: node.js, ssh, gitlab, nvm

I have a Node app that uses a specific version of node, so I use nvm to trigger the correct version in the `.npmrc` file.

The app is deployed with Gitlab. The process is simple: when I push from local to gitlab repo, gitlab will connect to the production server via ssh and pull the latest version of the repo in Gitlab

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$K8S_SECRET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

stages:
  - deploy_production

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy_production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - ssh myuser@example.com 'export NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} && cd www/myproject && rm -rf node_modules dist/* && git pull && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use && eval "[ -f .nvmrc ] && nvm install || nvm install stable" && nvm use --delete-prefix && npm ci && npm run prod'
    - ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && nvm use --delete-prefix"
```

The problem is in the last script. I get this response:

```
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to /usr/home/myuser/www/myproject/dist/client-report.html
$ ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && nvm use --delete-prefix"
bash: nvm: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

If I enter directly from my local terminal to the deployment server and ask for the NVM_DIR variable I can get it as expected:

```
ssh myuser@example.com
cd www/myproject
echo $NVM_DIR
$~/home/myuser/.nvm
```

But if I add a script to my gitlab-ci.yml with this same action:

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$K8S_SECRET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

stages:
  - deploy_production

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy_production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - ssh myuser@example.com 'export NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} && cd www/myproject && rm -rf node_modules dist/* && git pull && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use && eval "[ -f .nvmrc ] && nvm install || nvm install stable" && nvm use --delete-prefix && npm ci && npm run prod'
    - ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && echo $NVM_DIR"
    - ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && nvm use --delete-prefix"
```

The result is empty

```
[…]
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to /usr/home/myuser/www/myproject/dist/client-report.html
$ ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && echo $NVM_DIR"

$ ssh myuser@example.com "cd www/myproject && nvm use --delete-prefix"
bash: nvm: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What can I do to trigger NVM in `example.com` via ssh in gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 3):

When you log in, your environment (in particular, the variable `NVM_PATH` but also `PATH` itself which causes "bash: nvm: command not found") is different than when executing commands with the SSH command. You can check this like so:

```
ssh myuser@example.com
env
# vs:
ssh myuser@example.com env
```

The first will execute—depending on what shell and OS you use—files such as `.bashrc` which execute after an interactive login, the second will (often) not. An excerpt of what NVM adds:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

The first defines the variable you're missing, the second executes a script that among other things, alters your `PATH` so that the `nvm` executable can be found.

You can [execute this file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820533) or add [the snippet that NVM adds](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) to your CI pipeline before calling `nvm use`.

Comment: I can confirm that adding that snippet to source nvm.sh worked. Used it in a deploy.sh with Github actions.