# Installed java disappears after reboot on raspian

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, sdkman

I have a problem with the installation of java (jdk17) on raspian (Raspian 11 (bullseye). I need jdk17 but raspian packagemanager only want to install jdk11 so i decided to use sdkman. Using the tutorial here:https://foojay.io/today/installing-java-with-sdkman-on-raspberry-pi/
I installed sdkman and then java (17.0.6.-zulu), but when I restart the pi java is gone, even java -version does not work.

I look if my sd card is readonly, but it isn't the typed and used commands also remain in the bash history and sdkman files are also at their location after reboot.

How can I install java on my pi?

Comment: run command `sdk default java`

Comment: @life888888 Then comes the message "java 17.0.6-tem isnot available"

Comment: `java 17.0.6-tem` is `Temurin`, not `17.0.6.-zulu` , try to run command again `sdk install java 17.0.6.-zulu` , and run `sdk default java 17.0.6.-zulu`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a simpler aproach than useing sdkman. Simply use:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```

Still wondering about the use of sdkman...

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default, sdkman adds itself to `~/.bashrc` which is not executed when you ssh to your machine.

Here is a discussion about it:
[.bashrc at ssh login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login)

You can add to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```