# Cannot activate conda environment on remote with ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, conda

I am writing a `bash` shell script that I can run on my local computer to update and redeploy a simple app hosted on an AWS E2 instance. I am having trouble with one line in particular: I cannot seem to activate a `conda` environment within the `ssh` command.

`ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns "conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME"`

Returns:
`bash: line 1: conda: command not found`

However, if I ssh in with `ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns` and then run `conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME` separatly this works fine.

What is happening? All other commands in my shell script are working fine with the `ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns "COMMAND"` syntax.

My instance is running Ubuntu 22.04 if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I found my `.bashrc` file contained the following lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I solved this problem by simply moving my `conda` block above this line. I found this from the "community wiki"-owned response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login).

What I tried:

- Sourcing my `.bashrc` file prior to running `conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME`. This did not solve the issue, apparently because it was still leaving the script on my non-interactive session.
- Sourcing `.bashrc` in a `.bash_profile` file, which is recommended as another top answer in the thread linked above. While this does work in sourcing `.bashrc`, it still exists at the non-interactive condition.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns "conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
> ```
>
> Returns: `bash: line 1: conda: command not found`

Because the `conda` command is not found in the path.

> However, if I ssh in with `ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns` and
> then run `conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME` separatly this works fine.

Plausible.

> What is happening?

Your `conda` command is not present in the system's default path.  Likely you have installed a personal copy rather than a system-wide copy.  Your personal shell setup scripts, `.bash_profile` and / or `.bashrc` prepare your *interactive* shells to run the `conda` command, but these are not read when you launch a shell non-interactively, as `ssh` does on your behalf in the first example.

You could do something like

```
ssh -i $private_key_file $public_dns ". .bashrc && conda activate ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
```

, but I don't see the point, because the shell in which you activate `conda` terminates immediately afterward, mooting the whole exercise.  Whatever it is you want to run in your conda environment, consider writing a wrapper script on the E2 side that takes care of running it in the right environment.

Comment: Thanks @John. Got it, so ideally I would simply install conda system wide so it should be in the default path? In this case, the `. .bashrc && ` piece did not resolve the issue nor was it necessary. My `.bashrc` file contained a line to escape non-interactive runs, prefaced with the comment `# If not running interactively, don't do anything.`  I had to place my `conda`/`mamba` initialization above this line.