# How do I set $PATH such that `ssh user@host command` works?

Tags: unix, shell, path, ssh

I can't seem to set a new $PATH such that it is used when executing commands via `ssh user@host command`.  I have tried adding `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/new_path` to ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile on the remote machine, but executing `ssh user@host "echo \$PATH"` shows that the change has not been picked up (it shows /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games).  The remote machine is running Ubuntu 8.04.

I'm sure I could hack it into /etc/profile, but that's not a clean solution and it only works when one has root access.

Comment: I have tried adding `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/new_path` to both ~/.bash_login and ~/.bash_profile (in addition to the previously-tried ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile).  Neither works.  In both cases I had to create the file.

Comment: In my particular use case, it is not easy to modify the command sent to ssh.  I am using stfufs (http://www.guru-group.fi/too/sw/stfufs/), which constructs the ssh command itself.  I realize its method is not a great solution, but it would be nice to fix it without modifying stfufs.

Comment: You could put an ssh wrapper in stfufs' way, call the real ssh with modified args, if that's easier

Comment: just notifying that in this example there is a chance that you won't get the expected result due the double-quotes. see https://serverfault.com/questions/368327/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-when-passing-command-through

Answer (score 192, accepted):

As grawity said, ~/.bashrc is what you want, since it is sourced by non-interactive non-login shells.

I expect the problem you're having has to do with the default Ubuntu ~/.bashrc file.  It usually starts with something like this:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

You want to put anything for non-interactive shells *before* this line.

Comment: Yep, I moved the `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/new_path` above that line and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: .bashrc is unreliable. man bash: "Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection". This works on RHEL, but not on Archlinux. I had to edit /etc/environment to change the default PATH

Comment: You should add mention of `.zshenv` for zsh users, it took me quite a while to find it in the comments on other answers

Comment: on MacOS Catalina, I had to put a "zshenv" file at /etc/zshenv (with my export paths).

Comment: @Doomd: did ~/.zshenv not work for you?  It worked for me...  And yes, this answer would benefit from being edited to include information for various other shells, as well (zsh, fish, ...)

Answer (score 30):

Do you have an `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile`?

Bash in interactive mode checks for these files, and uses the **first existing one**, in this order:

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bash_login`
3. `~/.profile`

So if you have an `~/.bash_profile`, then whatever changes you do to `~/.profile` will be left unseen.

Bash in non-interactive mode *sometimes* reads the file `~/.bashrc` (which is also often source'd from the interactive scripts.) By "sometimes" I mean that it is distribution-dependent: quite oddly, there is a compile-time option for enabling this. Debian enables the `~/.bashrc` reading, while e.g. Arch does not.

`ssh` seems to be using the non-interactive mode, <del>so `~/.bashrc` should be enough. When having problems like this, I usually add a few echo's to see what files are being run.</del>

Comment: Adding the echos helped... but I'm still chasing down a way to execute 'ssh -X remotemachine "xterm"' and have the full system / user path from /etc/profile and ~/home/username/.bash_profile.  If I source both file in the command, it works.. but its ugly : ).

Comment: How do you know that "Bash in non-interactive mode reads the file `~/.bashrc`"? I do not see this statement in the manpage. Thanks

Comment: If you want a non-interactive non-login shell to source `~/.bashrc`, it seems that you need to additionally set the environment variable `BASH_ENV`; see http://superuser.com/a/585699/100843 . For non-interactive login shells, you'd probably have to modify one of the three startup scripts you mentioned.

Comment: For ZSH the non-interactive file is: `.zshenv`

Comment: @math `.zshenv` is always sourced; it doesn't matter if it's interactive or not.

Answer (score 20):

ssh documentation says:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

which is why adding to the bashrc files doesn't work. you do however have the following options:

1. If the `PermitUserEnvironment` option is set in the sshd config, you can add your PATH setting to `~/.ssh/environment`
2. `ssh remotemachine 'bash -l -c "somecommand"'`

Comment: 1. It's not set in my sshd config and `man sshd_config` says it's off by default so it's unlikely this solution would work for most people.

2. This would work, but I can't easily modify the command sent to ssh (see the second comment on my question).

Comment: 1. Does not work as expected, because in ~/.ssh/environment, you cannot add pathes to PATH, because $PATH will not be resolved.

Answer (score 8):

You can always say:

```
ssh remotemachine 'export PATH=wedontneedastinkingpath; echo $PATH'
```

Comment: This solution does not need any change on the remote machine, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @signpolyma answer, you will have to add your export before these lines

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: I actually just commented out these lines altogether - found in ~/.bashrc in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop.  No everything works.  Also set PermitUserEnvironment  to yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem myself, solved it with:

```
ssh user@remotehost PATH=\$HOME/bin:\$PATH\; remote-command
```