# How do I make ruby's `system` call aware of my `.bash_profile` aliases?

Tags: ruby, bash

I'd like to be able to call one of my shortcuts (i.e., aliases) from within a ruby program. In other words, I want

```
system('cpl')
```

to be the equivalent of writing

```
cd ~/Documents/CPlusPlus
```

at the command line, because my `.bash_profile` includes the line

```
alias cpl="cd ~/Documents/cplusplus"
```

I'm on a Mac OSX, and while my `.bash_profile` lives in the usual place (`~`), I might be writing ruby in/to any old folder. I am using Ruby 2.2.0 which is located in `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From `source` docs:](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context.

[From `shopt -s expand_aliases` docs](http://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html):

> If set, aliases are expanded. This option is enabled by default for interactive shells.

You use non-interactive shell, so this additional step is required:

```
system %(
  source ~/.bash_profile
  shopt -s expand_aliases
  cpl
)
```

Comment: I think this way is less risky than invoking bash as an interactive shell when it's not an interactive shell, and thus the better solution, except that the system shell is not guaranteed to be `bash` (on OS X it very likely is, though, unless the user has changed their environment)…

Answer (score 8):

The following should work:

```
system("bash -ci 'cpl'")
```

The `c` switch tells to "execute" `cpl` as a command instead of searching for a file. The `i` turns bash into interactive mode and more importantly loads the `.bashrc` file.

**EDIT:** Make sure you define your alias in the `.bashrc` file. This file is loaded every a new shell initializes. The `.bash_profile` is only loaded upon every user login. See more [here](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

Comment: Works great. Btw can you please explain why ``source  ~/.bashrc`` returns `sh: 1: source: not found`. I referred here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5313701/3035830

Comment: @shivam because there is no `source` command in `sh`, equivalent of `source` in `sh` is `.`

Comment: Note that this may be a bit risky if the user has something in their `.bashrc` that triggers for interactive shells, when this is not in fact an interactive shell.