# Building a C++ formula for homebrew

Tags: c++, ruby, homebrew, package-managers

I have very very little experience with Ruby and I was trying to build a simple homebrew formula.  I had a simple test project with the following structure

```
.
├── Makefile
└── test.cpp

0 directories, 2 files
```

And then I have the following `.rb` formula file

```
class Testbrew < Formula
  desc ""
  homepage ""
  url ""
  version ""
  head ""
  sha256 ""

  def install
    # system "make"
    # system("g++ -std=c++14 -O3 test.cpp -o testbrew")
    system "g++", "-std=c++14",
           "-O3",
           "-Wall",
           "-Werror",
           "-Wextra",
           "-pedantic",
           "-Wvla",
           "test.cpp",
           "-o testbrew"
    bin.install "testbrew"
    ohai("Done!")
  end
end
```

The confusing part here is that the first two commented lines of `system` work to install the package but the third does not, any idea why?  If I try the third line I get the error

```
==> g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -Wvla test.cpp -o testbrew
Error: No such file or directory - testbrew
```

Also as a followup, are there certain things that the function call `system()` does not allow the user to do?  i.e. are there any security restrictions imposed (for example with `ptrace`)?

Comment: `system` will not be aware of your `bash_profile`, so maybe `testbrew` is not getting added to the `PATH` like it does regularly. Maybe trying passing an absolute path. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555822/how-do-i-make-rubys-system-call-aware-of-my-bash-profile-aliases

Comment: @maxple but then how does the second `system()` call work in the same situation?  The second one works just fine and `bin.install` is able to copy it into the required directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument `"-o testbrew"` is wrong. That parses as `-o` with the option `" testbrew"` *including* the space. This is only possible because `system` with mutiple arguments bypasses the normal shell parsing, you're directly responsible for correctly splitting arguments.

You've broken the other arguments out correctly. I'd recommend doing it that way:

```
"-o", "testbrew"
```