# Activate Virtualenv Wrapper with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, python-3.x, capistrano3, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to deploy a Django project with Capistrano. Capistrano deploys the code to my server and finishes deploy steps.

But when I try add a custom task like this...

```
task :collect_static do
  on roles(:app) do |host|
    execute "cd #{release_path}/myproject"
    execute "workon myproject"
    execute "./manage.py collectstatic"
  end
end

after "deploy:updated", "collect_static"
```

It throws the following error...

```
02 bash: workon: command not found
```

After the deploy, if I SSH manually onto server and run workon command it works fine(same user). Just Capistrano doesn't recognise it?

Comment: Probably an issue with .bashrc or .profile not being loaded, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978564/invoking-bash-aliases-in-rake). What does `type workon` return?

Comment: Yeah I've tried "source ~/.bashrc and .profile" but no joy. Not sure how to get Capistrano to acknowledge it.

Comment: Could also be that you're using execute instead of system. What does `type workon` return when you enter it in the console?

Comment: type workon returns "workon is a function \n workon() {function code displayed}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workon` is not a program but a shell function from `virtualenvwrapper`. For `bash` to find it you have to source `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in the shell.

Comment: Switching from "workon" to "source /path/to/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/activate" works. Thank you for your help.