# aliases and shopt -s expand_aliases don't work in conditionals

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, alias

In a non-interactive bash script, these work:

```
alias hi="echo hi"
shopt -s expand_aliases
hi

alias hi="echo hi"
if [[ 1 ]]; then
    shopt -s expand_aliases
fi
hi

shopt -s expand_aliases
if [[ 1 ]]; then
    alias hi="echo hi"
fi
hi

alias hi="echo hi"
shopt -s expand_aliases
if [[ 1 ]]; then
    hi
fi
```

But these do not

```
alias hi="echo hi"
if [[ 1 ]]; then
    shopt -s expand_aliases
    hi #hi: command not found
fi

shopt -s expand_aliases
if [[ 1 ]]; then
    alias hi="echo hi"
    hi #hi: command not found
fi
```

**Can anyone explain why?**

Could it be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502451/1888983)?

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.

Does this mean entire bash conditionals read before execution?

Comment: Yes, I think it's related to the link you give; it's because aliases defined inside compound commands (functions, groups, blocks of `if`/`else`, etc) are not available from within this group. That's because Bash parses the whole command, and alias expansions and keywords processing occurs before command execution. And `alias` is a command...

Comment: You should consider shell functions instead of aliases anyhow.