# How to execute a command which defined in a remote file with ansible?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, alias

Now in a remote host, there is a `file:/root/.c`, which define an following alias command:

```
alias d="mysql -hxxxx -P3306 -uroot  --default-character-set=utf8 db2"
```

Then in my local host, I execute:

```
ansible 10.10.130.30 -m shell -a "source /root/.c && d -e 'show databases;'"
10.10.130.30 | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: d: command not foundnon-zero return code
```

How can ansible execute the `d` command?

Answer (score 0):

[Aliases are not expanded in a non-interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work).

Aliases are really meant only as a convenience for interactive sessions. If you want to make it easier for your non-interactive connections -- like Ansible -- to run a long command, just put it in a shell script.  For example, make `/root/connect-to-db.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -hxxxx -P3306 -uroot --default-character-set=utf8 db2 "$@"
```

Make it executable (`chmod 755 connect-to-db.sh`), and then run your `ansible` command like this:

```
ansible 10.10.130.30 -m command -a "/root/connect-to-db.sh -e 'show databases'"
```

---

If you really need alias expansion to work, you could accomplish what you want with the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: 10.10.130.30
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: |
        shopt -s expand_aliases
        . /root/.c
        d
      register: output

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

This won't work with the ad-hoc `ansible` command, because [aliases aren't available on the same line or in the same function where they are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502451/147356). We need a multiline shell script in order for the `shopt` command to take effect before sourcing `/root/.c`.

Comment: cause the remote host is belong to other company， i can't do like this. thanks anyway

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information.