# How do I call an alias that is defined within a function that is chained before the alias calling?

Tags: bash

The question is probably hard to understand so it's probably better with an illustrative example.

```bash
echo "function testcmd() { alias echo-test='echo test'; } " > define_testcmd; source defin
e_testcmd && testcmd && echo-test
```

throws a error `echo-test: command not found`.

Calling `echo-test` after this line works.

Comment: You can't. Use a function instead

Comment: I concur; don't use aliases. Perhaps tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239089/why-would-i-create-an-alias-which-creates-a-function though it is basically about the opposite case.

Comment: You can't use an alias on the same line where it's defined; see Dennis Williamson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501056/cant-get-expand-aliases-to-take-effect/2502451#2502451). Basically, aliases are kluges, with lots of weird limitations and sharp edges. Use functions instead.