# Why my ~/.bashrc is sourced while I'm connected and not when I only execute a command?

Tags: bash, ssh, aix

I have a target AIX 6.1 server where I need to execute a script.

The `~/.bashrc` on my target server is configured to add a variable `MACHINE=1`

When I ssh the server and connect I effectively view the `~/.bashrc` variables in my env:

```
[user@source ~]$ ssh user@10.10.10.10
[user@target]
$env |grep "MACHINE"
MACHINE=1
[user@target]
$
```

But when I execute directly the `env` command in the ssh the variable is not set:

```
[user@source ~]$ ssh user@10.10.10.10 "env" |grep MACHINE
[user@source ~]$
```

Is there something to configure more on the server?

Comment: What does `ssh user@10.10.10.10 "env"` print out. I mean without `grep`

Comment: It print a lot of variables exept the ones defined in ~/.bashrc

Comment: This link also deals a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc

Comment: As specified at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles, behavior on non-login non-interactive shells is implementation-defined; there's a non-default compile-time option which enables sourcing of `~/.bashrc` on these systems, but whether it's enabled is under your OS vendor's control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have is to tell `sshd` to set the environment variables for you. In `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

In `~/.ssh/environment`:

```
MACHINE=1
```

Comment: In my config the `sshd_config` was not here but this solution worked as an alternative.   That's doesn't explains how it worked on my old server but this solution might be cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLaffont Some operating systems enable a non-default compile-time flag causing `.bashrc` to be sourced even on non-interactive, non-login shells. This may be why your old system worked.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` remote command execution happens in a non-interactive shell.  As such, your `${HOME}/.bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc` aren't read.

If you want `ssh` commands to read environment variables, add those to `/etc/profile`.

Alternatively, try hacks:

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 'source ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo ${MACHINE}'
```

Comment: In reality I have an old target server who's working and there is nothing in /etc/profile, so I don't know how this old server is working.

Comment: For the alternative I allready think on that but i can't because the ssh command is realized by an external program

Comment: It doesn't even happen in a shell. After connecting, the remote `sshd` is executing an instance of `env`, not a shell.

Comment: Wouldn't `ssh user@10.10.10.10 "source ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo ${MACHINE}` work?

Comment: @chepner Would that it were. `sshd` doesn't `execve()` directly, but always invokes a shell.

Comment: Yes it works with escaped dollars. But i can't use this I have no hand on the ssh call.

Comment: @devnull You'd need to use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: ...that is to say: `ssh user@10.10.10.10 'source ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo ${MACHINE}'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, thanks.  prevent local shell from expanding!

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLaffont If the client is using double-quotes, then their shell is expanding the variables before the command is ever given to ssh, so the replacements are already done before the server sees it. If that's the problem, it's not something you can fix from the server side.

Comment: yes no problem with expanding shells, the problem is server side

Comment: I need to execute a command on the server with a variable defined on the server. But executed remotely by a client I can't modify. There is allready working on an old server so it's possible (with the existing client command). I'm now looking on server conf a way to set variable when a command is executed directly by ssh.