# RVM won't work over SSH (as a function)

Tags: ruby, function, ssh, terminal, rvm

I just installed RVM on a Debian 6 server, without having any problem in the beginning. However after everything is set up, I can't run RVM in the terminal. The message I get when I type `rvm use` is:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I am logging in via SSH and can´t find a solution for this problem. In "[rvm installation not working: "RVM is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)" they managed to solve the problem but not for SSH.

Comment: Please read the *entire* [installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), including the troubleshooting information toward the bottom of the page. If that doesn't help I'd recommend asking for help in the RVM IRC channel. RVM works fine remotely; I have it on multiple machines accessed via SSH.

Answer (score 3):

run:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

it will remove and re-add rvm lines from shell initialization files

for `ssh` connections to work you need to set your shell as `bash`(preferred) or `zsh`, you can check your current shell with:

```
getent passwd $USER | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

and if it is not `bash`/`zsh` change it with:

```
chsh $USER --shell `which bash`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to source `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` first. Add the following line to your `.bashrc` (or type it at the prompt) :

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Alternatively, if you need a function, the following script works for me :

```
#!/bin/sh

#RVM stuff
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then

  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then

  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"

else

  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"

fi
```

Comment: It's not working, just tried the first solution and it isn't working.
The same message appears.

Comment: Well, that's what solved the exact same problem on my Debian squeeze box... Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @swordofpain    where do you put your script? I assume it loads on every boot.

Answer (score -1):

When SSH launches bash, bash doesn't source .bashrc, in default builds (there is a compile-time flag, `SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC`, that forces it to). Try using something like this in your SSH command line:

```
ssh user@host "bash -i"
```

See [ssh command execution doesn't consider .bashrc | .bash_login | .ssh/rc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc).

Comment: Won't work either. I've just tried it and the problem persists.