# Discourse installation - Install necessary gems gives an error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, discourse

I am trying to install Discourse following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ubuntu.md), but the instruction

```
# Install necessary gems
bundle install --deployment --without test
```

gives this error

```
discourse@ubuntu:/var/www/discourse$ bundle install --deployment --without test
Gemfile syntax error:
/var/www/discourse/Gemfile:45: syntax error, unexpected
':', expecting $end
gem 'seed-fu-discourse', require: 'seed-fu'
                                 ^
```

How can I fix this?

---

---

**EDIT**

It seems that I am using ruby less then 1.9. But I am confused about this. As per the installation instructions I enter

```
# Build and install ruby
rvm install 2.0.0
```

But then I check the version

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

And I try (as per one of the comments)

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I go visit the [referenced site](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/) but I cannot change the gnome terminal settings, because I am working with a ubuntu server with no GUI. I've been trying to do it from command line through `.bashrc` but so far I could not. I have a question about this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/695710/rvm-is-not-a-function-selecting-rubies-with-rvm-use-will-not-work).

Comment: Which version of Ruby? Seems like you're using pre 1.9 with old hashrocket syntax.

Comment: Looks like you're using Ruby 1.9 hash syntax in ruby < 1.9

Comment: `rvm use 1.9.3` if using rvm.

Comment: @Bartosz this does not work. I edited by answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I am installing Rubu 2.0 but `ruby -v` shows 1.8. I edited by my answer with additional info.

Comment: @zrl3dx Apparently `ruby 1.8.7` but I installed 2.0. I edited by question.

Comment: Did you change the shell settings as told?

Comment: @Bartosz I am working with a ubuntu server from ssh. I am not seeing a GUI to change the shell settings. Let me know if I misunderstand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820549/rvm-wont-work-over-ssh-as-a-function

Comment: I strongly recommend to use rbenv instead of RVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `rvm use 2.0.0` so you will actually use it. Consider adding file named `.ruby-version` to root of your app with such content:

```
2.0.0
```

so since then rvm should change ruby version automatically when entering project dir.

About RVM is not a function... here it's described and answered: [rvm installation not working: "RVM is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thanks! especially for "RVM is not a function" link. It all worked.