# SSH into remote server and run commands in virtual environment

Tags: ssh, virtualenv

I am trying to execute a script sitting on my remote server. This script activates a virtual environment and then executes some commands. Now I want to execute this script directly from my mac terminal.
This is the content of the script

```
cd ~/workdir/
workon myvirtualenv
source ~/prodStuff/envVars 
git pull origin master
supervisorctl -u admin -p password restart gunicorn
supervisorctl -u admin -p password status
deactivate
```

This script works fine when I login to the server and execute it. But when I try to execute the same from mac's terminal, it gives me the following error

```
/home/ubuntu/scripts/deploy_code.sh: line 2: workon: command not found
```

So essentially, I am unable to switch to virtual environment. This is the command I am using to execute the script from my terminal

```
ssh prodserver ". /home/ubuntu/scripts/deploy_code.sh"
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: How and where is `workon` defined?

Comment: workon is bash command only which activates the virtual environment. And it works if I login to my remote machine and then type in this command

Comment: Yes. And how and where is this command defined? Is it an alias, a script, or something else? What is the output of `type workon`?

Comment: Output of type workon shows
"workon is a function"

Comment: rewrite it in your favorite language?

Comment: @tripleee got solution form your hint. The workon function was defined in the virtual-environment wrapper script. I sourced that file before executing workon and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh command execution doesn't consider .bashrc | .bash\_login | .ssh/rc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. 
I had conda virtual env which i would activate using : `source activate py36`.
Being a conda env it was actually stored in **/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/**.

So the right way to activate this env was `source /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/activate py36`.
But since path to this env was stored in my system , which i verified with command `echo $PATH`. my server knew where to look when i wrote `source activate py36`.
Unfortunately when you ssh from a remote machine, the server doesnt know where to look. so if you provide the entire path to the env like `source /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/activate py36` it will work.

You need to find out what kind of virtual env you have and then where its actually located.