# Export variable in remote .bashrc

Tags: bash, remote-server

Using Linux and bash:

in remote `.bashrc` file I've `export FOO="hello"`

locally I run this command but none variable was showed

```sh
ssh user1@192.168.1.114 ". /home/user1/.bashrc && echo \$FOO"
```

How could I get remote FOO variable?

Comment: If you want to track what's happening, add a `set -x` to your command. That is: `ssh user1@192.168.1.114 $'PS4=\'${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+\'; set -x; . /home/user1/.bashrc && echo "$FOO"'`. Right now, there isn't enough information in this question for it to be answerable -- editing in the trace transcript `set -x` creates will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh command execution doesn't consider .bashrc | .bash_login | .ssh/rc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc)

Comment: @0stone0, the OP is _explicitly_ sourcing the remote `.bashrc`, so that makes it distinct from the questions about why that isn't happening automatically. And I don't see them trying to use local variables (and they're escaping their expansion to prevent local evaluation), so I don't think the first proposed duplicate is a match either. That said, I also don't think this is answerable; it shows us what they're doing right, but doesn't give us enough information to know what it is they're doing wrong.

Comment: Try this `ssh user1@192.168.1.114 '. /home/user1/.bashrc ; echo $FOO'`

Comment: Your command to print `FOO` is wrong. It's either `printenv ECHO` or `echo $FOO` to show the value of an exported variable.

Comment: @gekomad : Your question is a bit unclear to me. You are talking about a remote server, but the code you posted does not show any remote access.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
source <(ssh user1@192.168.1.114 cat /home/user1/.bashrc)
declare -p FOO
```

Output:

```
declare -x FOO="hello"
```

I assume `/home/user1/.bashrc` contains `export FOO="hello"`.

Comment: This solution solves partially my question