# Rails 3 -- Bundler/Capistrano Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

I have a basic Rails 3 app working locally on my development box, but want to test out deploying early on to make sure everything works.  I'm using Capistrano to deploy.

When I run `cap deploy` (after all the other necessary setup), it breaks on this command with this error:

```
[...]
* executing 'bundle:install'
* executing "bundle install --gemfile /var/www/trex/releases/20100917172521/Gemfile --path /var/www/trex/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"

servers: ["www.[my domain].com"]
[www.[my domain].com] executing command
** [out :: www.[my domain].com] sh: bundle: command not found
command finished
[...]
```

So it looks like it can't find the `bundle` command on the server.

However, when I log in to the server...

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.0
```

...the `bundle` command works just fine.

What could be going wrong?

-

(Furthermore, for completeness:)

```
$ which ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
$ which rails
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rails
$ which bundle
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/bundle
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

For RVM >= 1.11.3, you should now just use the [rvm-capistrano gem](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano).  For older RVM >= 1.0.1, the answer below still applies.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Okay, though I *still* haven't gotten a full `cap deploy` to work, I did fix *this* problem.  The problem was Capistrano trying to use a different path for Bundler (and other gems) than the RVM paths.

Check your Capistrano path by doing `cap shell`, then `echo $PATH`.  You'll probably see your standard `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`, but that's not where RVM has Bundler, et al., stored.

Edit your Capistrano `config/deploy.rb` file, and add the following lines, per [these instructions](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano):

```
# Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

# Load RVM's capistrano plugin.    
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user  # Don't use system-wide RVM
```

That finally got Capistrano to see Bundler and start loading gems appropriately.

Comment: I have rvm installed system wide and deploying with local user. To make it work I have to be sure that the user from which I am deploying have setuped the rvm right. The .bashrc troubleshooting described http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ here helped

Comment: Maybe you'll find yourself here if you tried to upgrade the rvm capistrano integration from what is listed here: http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email to the new approach mentioned in this answer. If you do remove the `default_environment` lines be sure to also remove `default_run_options[:shell] = 'bash'` otherwise you still won't have rvm on the capistrano shell.

Comment: That does not work for me. Only that works: set :bundle_cmd, 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && bundle'

Comment: This has changed, some time recently. You can now just do gem install rvm-capistrano to solve the issue

Comment: This will give you a warning now:  RVM - Capistrano integration was extracted to a separate gem, install: `gem install rvm-capistrano` and remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line

Comment: @jackquack -- the answer is now updated for newer versions of RVM.

Answer (score 26):

Bundler isn't found because .bash_profile is not being loaded and thus your PATH is wrong. This is probably because you have the RVM script in .bash_profile.

The simple answer is to move the RVM script from .bash_profile to .bashrc and Capistrano should be able to find it (also verify that .bash_profile sources .bashrc).

Capistrano uses SSH to execute commands on the server via a [non-interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-manu). This shell session will [source .bashrc but not .bash_profile](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html). I added an ECHO statement to both and ran an LS via SSH. You can see in the results below that only .bashrc is sourced:

```
$ ssh user@123.amazonaws.com ls
.bashrc loaded
git
file1
file2
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to always source your `.bash_profile` from your `.bashrc` ? That way your `.bash_profile` always gets sourced no matter whether it's an interactive or non-interactive shell

Answer (score 11):

I had an identical problem using rbenv. The solution was to take the rbenv specific lines from the bottom of my .bashrc file and put them at the top. The first line of my .bashrc file was returning aborting if the shell wasn't running in interactive mode.

Answer (score 7):

That last line should actually be

```
set :rvm_type, :user
```

that is, user must be a symbol and not a variable, otherwise you'll get

```
undefined local variable or method `user'
```

Answer (score 7):

No `rvm/capistrano` worked for me. The best solution I found was adding to `deploy.rb` file the following line (it's for non system-wide RVM):

`set :bundle_cmd, 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && bundle'`

Answer (score 2):

It was my understanding that the bundle command is not found because the PATH variable, defined in the user's ~/.bash_profile, isn't loaded by Capistrano.

To get around this I have created a task :bundle_gems.

```
task :bundle_gems do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-X.X.X/bin:$PATH && bundle install vendor/gems"
end
```

Note that I also include the path to PostgreSQL binaries - installation of the pg gem was failing because they could not be found, even when bundle could be found.

This seems like a messy approach, though. Presumably there is a more 'global' place to define paths to binaries that I don't know about.

**Update 23/12**

To add a directory to $PATH for all users: https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos

However this still won't be loaded because it is a non-interactive non-login shell.

One suggestion was to add the paths to /etc/bashrc: [How do I set $PATH such that `ssh user@host command` works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works)

However this also didn't work for me. I believe its because SSH doesn't load /etc/bashrc either.

Another suggestion was to edit ~/.ssh/environment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/79248. However this seems almost as messy as specifying the paths in deploy.rb.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

set :bundle_cmd, 'source $HOME/.bash_profile && bundle'

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of the suggestions.  Had problems with setting the paths in the deploy.rb file for the RVM environment.  My final solution was to include the following:

In the config/deploy.rb file add:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Also in config/deploy.rb, or in my case config/production.rb as I was using the multistage option for Capistrano

```
after "deploy", "rvm:trust_rvmrc"
```

This step simply ensures that we stop getting the 'do you want to trust the .rvmrc file' and it calls a task in the deploy.rb file such as:

```
namespace :rvm do
   task :trust_rvmrc do
      run "rvm rvmrc trust #{release_path}"
   end
end
```

After putting in these slight changes I was able to run `cap production deploy` which checked out the code; executed the asset pipeline deployment, linked up the release folder to current, executed `bundle install` and cleaned up.