# Capistrano deploy:cold doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, capistrano, setup-deployment

I have two Questions. One small and one greater problem.

1. Why i have to enter the passphrase 10 times my running cap:cold
2. After i tryed to setup an capistrano via teachmetocode-tuorial and
   with some helps of stackoverflow. I sat down, with many tutorials of deploying capistrano and write my own new Version of the deploy.rb
   Our gem env output looks so

   RubyGems Environment:

   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15

     - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-linux]
     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp
     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin
     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
     - GEM PATHS:

       - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp
       - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
     - GEM CONFIGURATION:

       - :update_sources => true
       - :verbose => true
       - :benchmark => false
       - :backtrace => false
       - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - REMOTE SOURCES:

       - http://rubygems.org/

And our deploy.rb is here

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "#{application}@myserver:/home/git/repos/#{application}.git"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{application}/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 5

server "myserver", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

set :branch, "master"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = false
default_run_options[:pty] = true

before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"

load 'deploy/assets'

namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

Our Developmentsetup
We use Apache+Passagner and the rvm installation of http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/.
On the server we install it on the same way. Every User(apps, gemsets or realuser) have to be a member of group rvm... We use modrails to install the passagner...
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installing_via_the_gem

But why get i an error when i use `cap deploy:cold`. The `cap deploy:check` say `You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed`
The error is here

```
 triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "ls -x /home/myapp/myapp/releases"
    servers: ["myserver"]
    [myserver] executing command
    [myserver] sh -c 'ls -x /home/myapp/myapp/releases'
    command finished in 82ms
  * executing "cd /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114 && bundle install --gemfile /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114/Gemfile --path /home/m
ahaloo/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["myserver"]
    [myserver] executing command
    [myserver] sh -c 'cd /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114 && bundle install --gemfile /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114/Gemfile --path /h
ome/myapp/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
 ** [out :: myserver] sh: bundle: not found
    command finished in 73ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114; true"
    servers: ["myserver"]
    [myserver] executing command
    [myserver] sh -c 'rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114; true'
    command finished in 171ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114 && bundle install --gemfile /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331143114/Gemfile --path /home/
myapp/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on myserver
marcus@lenny:~/dev/workspace/myapp$
```

Our `bundle list` is here

```
 * actionmailer (3.2.0)
 * actionpack (3.2.0)
 * activemodel (3.2.0)
 * activerecord (3.2.0)
 * activeresource (3.2.0)
 * activesupport (3.2.0)
 * arel (3.0.2)
 * builder (3.0.0)
 * bundler (1.1.1)
 * capistrano (2.11.2)
 * coffee-rails (3.2.1)
 * coffee-script (2.2.0)
 * coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
 * erubis (2.7.0)
 * execjs (1.3.0)
 * highline (1.6.11)
 * hike (1.2.1)
 * i18n (0.6.0)
 * journey (1.0.3)
 * jquery-rails (1.0.17)
 * json (1.6.5)
 * libv8 (3.3.10.4)
 * mail (2.4.4)
 * mime-types (1.17.2)
 * multi_json (1.1.0)
 * net-scp (1.0.4)
 * net-sftp (2.0.5)
 * net-ssh (2.3.0)
 * net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
 * polyglot (0.3.3)
 * rack (1.4.1)
 * rack-cache (1.2)
 * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
 * rack-test (0.6.1)
 * rails (3.2.0)
 * railties (3.2.0)
 * rake (0.9.2.2)
 * rdoc (3.12)
 * sass (3.1.15)
 * sass-rails (3.2.0)
 * simple_form (2.0.1)
 * sprockets (2.1.2)
 * sqlite3 (1.3.5)
 * therubyracer (0.9.10)
 * thor (0.14.6)
 * tilt (1.3.3)
 * treetop (1.4.10)
 * tzinfo (0.3.32)
 * uglifier (1.2.3)
 * uuidtools (2.1.2)
```

Can someone help us please to get a working capistrano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Capistrano path by doing **cap shell**, then **echo $PATH**. U'll probably see your standard /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin, but that's not where RVM has Bundler

Edit your Capistrano config/deploy.rb file, and add the following lines:

```
# Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

# Load RVM's capistrano plugin.    
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user  # Don't use system-wide RVM
```

[Rails 3 -- Bundler/Capistrano Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737678/rails-3-bundler-capistrano-errors)

Comment: Thanks @Said
That doesn't work :-( *tears in my eyes*
here are my error: :-(

Comment: `/home/myapp/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331153447; true"
    servers: ["myserver"]
    [myserver] executing command
    [myserver] rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331153447; true'
 ** [out :: myserver] bash: /home/myapp/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::CommandError, failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'rm -rf /home

Comment: the `$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))` is already removed from rvm, you need to use teh new gem rvm-capistrano

Answer (score 0):

To the problem 1 (type password many times):

You can generate a public/private key pair in your local machine with

`ssh-keygen -t rsa` (<kbd>Enter</kbd> for all)

This will generate two files in /home/LOCAL_USER/.ssh/ directory (id_rsa and **id_rsa.pub**)

Then in the server create or edit the file /home/user/.ssh/**authorized_keys** and add the content of the id_rsa.pub

With this, your local machine is authorized to access this server (**logging with user**) without asking password.

Comment: To the problem 2 (bundle not found) you can add in your deploy.rb
`set :bundle_cmd, "/path/to/your/bin/bundle"`

Comment: Ähm my problem is now. At the server is the is our bundle at 
`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle` and locally is the installation `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle` What can i do here?

Comment: The path of the server, where the command will execute: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle

Comment: :-( This does't run sorry
` [myserver :: out] bash: /home/myapp/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory
    command finished in 84ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331180124; true"
    servers: ["myserver"]
    [myserver] executing command
    [myserver] rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp' -c 'rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/
20120331180124; true'`

Comment: This is result of `set :bundle_cmd, "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle"` in deploy.rb?

Comment: Yes Thats right,
The error which is to solve
`[out :: myserver] bash: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm/rvm-shell: Not a directory`

Comment: I Added also `set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"`, with the serverpath from `which rvm`

Comment: I tryed to command the 
`#$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
#require "rvm/capistrano"`

Comment: I tryed to command the 
`#$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
#require "rvm/capistrano"` Now i have an new/other error but not the rvm error. I set the path by `set :rvm_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"` The new error is this

Comment: [myserver] sh -c 'cd /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120331213205 && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle install --gemfile /home/maha
loo/myapp/releases/20120331213205/Gemfile --path /home/myapp/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
 ** [out :: myserver] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0)

Comment: amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
 ** [out :: myserver] from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
 ** [out :: myserver] from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
 ** [out :: myserver] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

You did not used rvm-capistrano integration, the integration is described here:

- https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/

Please note that rvm-capistrano is no longer part of RVM installation, it's separate gem, you need to include it in your `Gemfile` and require in `config/deploy.rb` also do not forget to set `set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")`

Comment: :) This runs but it `failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp' -c 'cd /home/myapp/myapp/rel
eases/20120401103204 && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/bin/bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROU
PS=assets assets:precompile'" on myserver` Where is the last error

Comment: `rake aborted!
** [out :: myserver] Invalid CSS after "...ing: 20px 0; */": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(in /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120401103755/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
** [out :: myserver] 
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
command finished in 7986ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/myapp/myapp/releases/20120401103755; true"
servers: ["myserver"]
[myserver] executing command
[myserver] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp' -c 'rm -rf `

Comment: It runs :-) The Problem was the the local gems not equal to server gems ... Thanks to all