# Bundle: Not found with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've got some trouble to deploy my Rails App.

I've got this message:

```
sh: 1:
bundle: not found
```

Here is my gemfile (only capistrano part) :

```
gem "capistrano", "2.15.5"
```

Here is my deploy (just the important part about rbenv)

> set(:deploy_to) { "/home/#{user}/#{application}_#{rails_env}" }
>   set :default_environment, { 'PATH' => '$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH' }

On the server when I type`ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.0.0p247`. And when I type `which bundle` I get `/home/paul/.rbenv/shims/bundle`.

What's the problem? Why do I get this message?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 -- Bundler/Capistrano Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737678/rails-3-bundler-capistrano-errors)

Answer (score -1):

Capistrano executes the commands in a very basic shell so the $PATH environment are not the same as when you login through SSH.

One way to solve this is by setting PermitUserEnvironment to yes in `/etc/sshd_config` and then add the correct PATH to `~/.ssh/environment`

another way can be to

In you `config/deploy.rb` add the following snippet

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/:$PATH"
}
```

Comment: Where shoul I add PermitUserEnvironment ? On the server or on my computer ?

Comment: on the server go and paste the code snippet in `config/deploy.rb`