# How to modify PATH for non-interactive SSH call in RHEL 5?

Tags: unix, ssh, redhat, rhel5

I am trying to modify the PATH variable of my SSH server such at a non-interactive shell command `ssh myserver.com 'echo $PATH'` returns the desired path. I tried modifying ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile files but they only modify PATH for when I log in to the server interactively, i.e. `ssh myserver.com`.

Can I change this behavior in RHEL5?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works

Answer (score 0):

**~/.bash_profile** is where you want to place these variables. I don't believe that bash uses ~/.profile ( I believe it is used by csh and tcsh )