# How to configure remote PATH when running remote SSH commands?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, ssh

I installed PM2 globally on Debian 10 (buster) using the following approach.

```sh
npm config set prefix ~/.local
echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
npm -g install pm2
```

When I run `ssh user@host pm2 ls`, I get `pm2: command not found`.

It is my understanding that SSH commands run in non-interactive shells that do not source `~/.bashrc`. Is this assumption correct?

Is there a way to work around this limitation without using an absolute path for `pm2`?

The above proof of concept is simplified. I am actually running a remote script that calls other scripts. Using an absolute path would make the scripts deployment-specific which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/941995/4579271.

I had to add `export PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH` at the top of `~/.bashrc`.

On Debian 10 (buster), `~/.bashrc` includes instructions to return when shell is non-interactive.

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```