# Git failing with "Server aborted the SSL Handshake"

Tags: git, ssl, bitbucket, handshake

I am working with a Bitbucket repository and simply trying to push my code. I see this error message **only when working on my home wifi** (AT&T U-Verse):

`fatal: unable to access 'https://<link to the repository>': Server aborted the SSL handshake`

I have been searching but found no helpful answers as to why this might be happening.

**Update**:

The `git push` command has been sporadically successful, but fails at least 9 times out of 10

Comment: possibly `bitbucket` is blocked by your ISP. (try proxy)

Comment: Are you able to access https://<link to the repository> from your browser without any certificate errors? Does the site have a valid certificate as seen from your browser?

Comment: It's already answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936678/git-and-server-aborted-the-ssl-handshake-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936678/git-and-server-aborted-the-ssl-handshake-errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git and "Server aborted the SSL handshake" errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936678/git-and-server-aborted-the-ssl-handshake-errors)

Comment: Check out my comment on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999195/why-is-this-git-clone-command-failing/47047815#47047815

Answer (score 0):

- First, make sure your account is correct and accessible.
- The second is to determine whether the next version is up-to-date.
- Third, without the previous two points, there still appears the following command line that I can try to verify on my mac: brew install curl

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Happened because my git was trying to use an outdated Bitbucket IP.

- So I added/updated Bitbucket in the `~/private/etc/hosts` file
- Their new IPs (since 2018) are specified [here](https://bitbucket.org/blog/new-ip-addresses-bitbucket-cloud), I'm using the IPv6 one.