# Setting up a git repo on my GoDaddy hosting plan

Tags: git

I have a project which is version-controlled using git.

What I want to be able to do is set up a repo on my (ssh-enabled) GoDaddy shared hosting package so that I can deploy with a push rather than dragging and dropping in FTP.

Any tips would be appreciated. Best would be an account from someone who's already done it, but I couldn't personally find any online.

Comment: For reference, I gave up on this and got a VPS from slicehost.

Comment: Update: For reference the latest version of godaddy shared hosting now has git installed by default.

Answer (score 10):

With a little work, I was able to get Git running on my GoDaddy account.  There's a longer posting detailing the process on [my blog](http://johntrammell.com/wp/2011/01/05/using-git-on-godaddy/), but the short answer is:

1. install git in your account (perhaps using the tarball referenced in my blog post)
2. create a git repository (bare or not) in your account
3. check out your repository, using -u to indicate the path to `git-upload-pack`

   % git clone -u libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack mysite:myrepo.git
4. tweak your local repository config to point to the correct paths to `git-upload-pack` and
   `git-receive-pack`:

   % git config remote.origin.receivepack libexec/git-core/git-receive-pack
    % git config remote.origin.uploadpack libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack

---

Since the blog is no longer accessible, here is the full post pulled from [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20110830112931/http://johntrammell.com/wp/2011/01/05/using-git-on-godaddy/):

### Using Git on GoDaddy

This blog is hosted on a cheap GoDaddy account.  When shell access over SSH was recently made available, I thought it would be fun to install local git repositories.  It wasn’t trivial, but I did finally get it working.  Here’s how I did it:

#### Step 0.  Configure SSH

You want to create a public key so you can SSH in to your GoDaddy account painlessly.  Create a key pair if you don’t already have one, and add it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  I’ll assume an entry in `~/.ssh/config` something like this:

```
Host mysite
HostName mygodaddysite.com
User mylogin
```

#### Step 1. Install Git

After poking around on my GoDaddy host, I discovered it was running CentOS 5.2.  Binaries running on my laptop weren’t compatible, so I used VirtualBox to set up a local Centos 5.2 install and build Git.  I’m sharing a tarball containing the [pre-built CentOS 5.2 Git binaries](http://johntrammell.com/centos5.2-git.tar.gz). You should be able to download and install  with the commands:

```bash
wget http://johntrammell.com/centos5.2-git.tar.gz
tar xzf centos5.2-git.tar.gz
```

Enjoy this part–I’ve saved you a couple hours’ work here.

#### Step 2. Set up your environment.

Add the following to your .bash_profile:

```
export EDITOR=vim
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/libexec/git-core
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/libexec/git-core
export GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=~/share/git-core/templates
```

This will set your environment up correctly on an interactive shell.  Unfortunately I can’t seem to get the PATH to set correctly for non-interactive SSH commands.  For example, when I run this command from my laptop:

```bash
ssh mysite env
```

I see the default PATH.  This is also the case when I set the path in .bashrc.  I haven’t tracked down exactly what SSH does on non-interactive access, but this may be related to the PermitUserEnvironment setting in sshd.  Luckily we can work around this.

#### Step 3. Creating a repository

Log in to your GoDaddy account, and create a simple “bare” Git repository:

```bash
% mkdir myrepo
% cd myrepo
% touch README
% git init
% git add README
% git commit -m 'empty git repository'
% cd ..
% git clone --bare myrepo myrepo.git
```

You now have a bare repository in `~/myrepo.git/` in the root of your GoDaddy account.

#### Step 4. Checking out your repository

The only tricky part to this is that you have to tell git where to find git-upload-pack.  This works around the PATH problem mentioned above.  On your local machine, do this:

```bash
git clone -u libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack mysite:myrepo.git
```

You should now have a copy of the original minimal repository checked out.

#### Step 5. More git configuration tweaks

Sadly we are not done:

```bash
% cd myrepo
% echo "foo" > README
% git commit -am 'updated'
[master 044c086] updated
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
% git push
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Our PATH problems are interfering with the push operation now.  As a workaround, we can either specify –receive-pack on the command line, or set it in the local configuration (the same applies for fetch operations and –upload-pack):

```bash
% git config remote.origin.receivepack libexec/git-core/git-receive-pack
% git config remote.origin.uploadpack libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack
```

Congratulations, you should be up and running now!

#### Resources

- http://johntrammell.com/centos5.2-git.tar.gz
- https://serverfault.com/questions/26836/setting-up-a-git-repo-on-my-godaddy-hosting-plan
- [Setting up a git repo on my GoDaddy hosting plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003885/setting-up-a-git-repo-on-my-godaddy-hosting-plan)
- [git-upload-pack: command not found, how to fix this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly)
- http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?20304-Bluehost-Solution-to-the-Git-PATH-issue-when-using-a-non-interactive-shell
- http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+setup
- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-upload-pack.html
- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-receive-pack.html

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a long time. I'm struggling with the same issue right now but I can't access your blog. Any chance you have it available elsewhere?

Comment: For future answer-seekers: web archive's version http://web.archive.org/web/20110830112931/http://johntrammell.com/wp/2011/01/05/using-git-on-godaddy/

Answer (score 3):

First, you will need to have git installed on GoDaddy.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  Git supports local user installs, but you need to have certain development tools handy to do it.  Download git, and see if you can `./configure && make && make install` -- if so, it will put it in your `~/bin` directory.

We use git extensively for controlling production.  But rather than deploying on push, may I suggest that you ssh to the box and do a `git pull` ?

More specifically, create a "Release" branch, and then when you are ready to deploy, simply merge your changes into the Release branch, ssh to the server, and git pull.

**For example**

```
ssh user@godaddyhost.com
cd /path/to/project

#ok, assuming you are on the Release branch
git fetch
git merge branch-with-new-changes-on-it

# update the remote Release branch with the merge
git push origin HEAD
```

This simple workflow allows developers to see **exactly** what is on the production server at all times, and to merge other changes in with theirs before asking for a deployment.  In fact, we require that all production changes be fully merged before requesting a deployment of your branch.

--

If you do manage to get git installed on GoDaddy, and you REALLY want to auto-deploy when you push to it, then take a look at the `post-update` hook.

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

--

If you cannot get git installed on GoDaddy, then see if they support rsync.  Then you can have a simple bash script somewhere that will

1. pull your changes
2. rsync them to godaddy

--

There are many ways to do it.  Perhaps this will help with direction a bit...

Answer (score 3):

I was successful following the directions here:

http://www.krizka.net/2010/12/30/setting-up-a-public-git-repository-with-godaddy-shared-hosting/

The keys (for me) were

- Getting the precompiled binary for CentOS (from a link in post above)
- Setting the "uploadpack" and "receivepack". This is step 1 in the section "Letting local git know about remote git" near the end of the post.

Comment: That was a great description, but the site is no longer avaialble.

Comment: Unfortunate - perhaps someone can dig it out of the internet time machine?

Answer (score 2):

I maitain git locally and use scp to push live... it's not elegant, but godaddy has scp installed my default.

"scp -r fooDirectory user@host.com:/path/to/document/root/"

that will move a local directory "fooDirectory" to "/path/to/document/root/fooDirectory" on the remote host.

when you are logged into go daddy use "pwd

Answer (score 2):

Connect via ssh.

Install git to ~/git.

After that create/update these files:

~/.ssh/authorized_keys

```
command="~/connect.sh" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...
```

~/connect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "${HOME}/.env_profile" ]; then
        source ~/.env_profile
fi;

if [ "x${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}x" == "xx" ]; then
        $SHELL --login
else
        eval "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}"
fi;
```

~/.env_profile

```
export ENV_VARIABLE=value
```

by git:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/git/libexec/git-core
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/git/lib
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/git/libexec/git-core
export GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=~/git/share/git-core/templates
```

I spent about a week to google this out, but it's working like charm now... I don't think there is another solution by godaddy accounts, the possibilities are too limited by them...

Comment: I used something similar and now git works like a charm but i still cant clone something thats in github into godaddys account. any hints? ssh doesnt have permission to execute :(

Comment: I never cloned from github. Maybe it does not use your local ssh to clone.

Answer (score 1):

I found another useful guide to install git on GoDaddy at http://www.612softwarefoundry.com/getting-git-on-godaddy/

Answer (score 0):

There is a YouTube tutorial explaining how to set up Git on a Godaddy Shared Hosting account. Here is the link:
http://youtu.be/z60GLfsGGsY

There is also a webpage with the commands that you will need to execute on the video. Here is the page address:
http://www.drupalfever.com/linux-how-to/git/set-up-git-in-a-godaddy-shared-hosting-account

If you have any question, leave me a note or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in this blog post worked for me, except that I had to visit EPEL and find the newest version of the git RPM: http://hire.chrisjlee.net/node/139

### Fetch the binaries

```
cd ~
mkdir git
cd git
# Download the rpm from EPEL ( http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL )
# Find the latest version by checking http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386.rpm
# Extract binaries from the rpm
rpm2cpio git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386.rpm  | cpio -imdv
rm git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386.rpm
```

### Configure

```
echo "
export GIT_BIN=${HOME}/git
export PATH=${GIT_BIN}/usr/bin:${PATH}
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=${GIT_BIN}/usr/bin
export GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=${GIT_BIN}/usr/share/git-core/templates
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true" >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Configure git

```
mkdir ~/.git
git config --local --add remote.origin.uploadpack ~/git/usr/bin/git-upload-pack
git config --local --add remote.origin.receivepack ~/git/usr/bin/git-receive-pack
```

Comment: if the .bashrc file doesn't run on login (as it didn't for me), then run `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up git on a VPS hosted at http://netgonian.com (GoDaddy reseller). What took 3 hours could have been done in about 15 minutes and super easy.

Installing git should be as simple as running `yum install git` but unfortunately trying that gave me all sorts of could not find file errors.  Below was the final solution.

Here are the steps:

1. ssh onto your virtual server
2. change over to the root user using the command `su -`
3. follow the instructions here to [create a new centos-base.repo file](http://redhat-centos.blogspot.com/2013/06/configuring-centos-base-repo-for-redhat.html)
4. in the same directory where you just created the above file (/etc/yum.repos.d) rename the file CentoOS-Base.repo to CentOS-Base.repox
5. now you can run `yum install git` and it will work.

The basic issue was that all the base urls for yum were pointing to some server on the secureserver.net that was missing all the needed files.  What we are doing above is pointing the base urls to servers that have the needed files.