# Git over ssh without Git being installed on server

Tags: git, ssh

I have full access  to some folder on a remote Linux server over ssh and scp. I can upload and download files but not install apps.  Now I want to put a git repository on this server. 
When I try to clone from an over scp copied repository I get the following error message:

```
sgit-upload-pack: Command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Cloning using the same command from Github works as expected. Do I need Git installed on the server? If yes, is there any work around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that git needs to be there. But you can simply install it in the directory you have access to.

Comment: How can I install git into user directory? apt-get (for Ubuntu) doesn't seem to have such an option.

Comment: You can install it manually. Download the source distribution from http://git-scm.com/download, unpack and then follow the instructions in INSTALL. You will probably need a compiler and so on.

Comment: To go along with what Roman said, on a Debian based system you should install build-essentials to get gcc and make and so forth.

Comment: The problem is, I  can install nothing. And Git  seems to have a lot of dependencies. I guess, I will give up compiling Git and try ... something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want to play, you could get a binary distribution for your linux and unpack it by hand (but you would still need the runtime dependencies).

Comment: To be more exact you need only `git-upload-pack` / `git-receive-pack` from the whole git installed somewhere; you can then pass appropriate option to "git clone" or "git push" respectively, to point where this command is on remote server.

Comment: @Mouk: the dependencies are: zlib, ssh (for SSH access), and of course build dependencies. The rest of dependencies you can configure out.

Comment: That's too bad. I'm currently needing this for a Solaris server on which git is simply not installable. I wish git could work like emacs's tramp.This morning i've found [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) which is a partial solution to push files.

Answer (score 8):

You could use SSHFS and mount the directory on your local machine, and then run Git locally.

Comment: You can do that using Dokan SSH Filesystem. I found a great tutorial : http://gusclass.com/blog/2012/12/27/remote-mounting-ssh-filesystems-from-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

You would need enhanced access for SSHFS, I would imagine.

This would be a really cool addition to Git, and I believe there *is* some way to do it, though I haven't found it... yet. I am using git in combination with rsync to the remote server for a similar situation.