# Does git need to be present on a server to use it?

Tags: git, dependencies

When I started with git, one of the most prominent benefits my colleagues told me, was that *git didn't need to be present on a server* opposed to svn.

But is this really true? In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509246/git-over-ssh-without-git-being-installed-on-server) I read that at least a `git-upload-pack` or `git-receive-pack` would be necessary.

On the other hand, I can safely have a git repository on an usb stick.

So, does the server need to have any software installed except to ssh or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you're correct when you're saying you can serve a git repository without have git installed on your server.
This is because everything that is needed to serve a git repository, is "stored" in the `.git` directory.

But, to communicate with a server (e.g. do a `clone`, `push`, etc...), based on your repository address (`refspec`) a certain transport will be used. And if you're using the `ssh` or `git` transport, the server side needs to have git installed as well. Because, like you said, it 'packs' all data that is exchanged in a more efficient format.

You could circumvent this by mounting remote server on your filesystem, and use the 'file' transport. Or you could upload your own 'alternatives' for git, and use that instead:

```
git clone -u /home/you/bin/git-upload-pack you@machine:code
```

(from: [git-upload-pack: command not found, how to fix this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly/1647238#1647238) )

Answer (score 0):

Every git respository acts like a server.

Once you do `git clone` it becomes a fully working repository that can be added as a remote in any other computer.

Comment: He is talking about the git software, not a repository.