# Is it necessary to have a git installed on remote host when pushing against it?

Tags: git, ssh

We are facing a problem, when git cannot be installed on remote machine. And we still require a git repository on there. We could use some php libs to do commits on repository without having git installed. But can we push against a workstation that doesn't have it? And how do we do that, if it's possible?

Comment: What's the problem with installing git on the remote side?

Comment: Why can't you install git on the remote system? A user install would be enough

Comment: I don't see a reason for the downvote? This is a valid question, albeit the goal is a little strange

Comment: All we have there is ftp access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317280/does-git-need-to-be-present-on-a-server-to-use-it

Comment: Why do you think it is not? It's the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone and push your repo to a network share on the remote machine, in this case git doesn't need to be installed. You can also clone and push to an FTP server.

I'm doing this at work, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted my post and there seems to be a smart workaround for that via shares: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141205/git-repository-on-ftp-server Must be even easier with ssh.

Comment: I was intrigued by "push to FTP server", but it seems that git itself doesn't support this. I've found this though: https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp. Is it what you had in mind when you wrote your advice?

Comment: @jayarjo for FTP I only read it was possible but haven't tried myself, I push to Smb shares (Windows environment)