# Git clone over ssh missing git-upload-pack

Tags: git

Clone attempt over ssh:

```
Cloning into repo...
Password:
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly


Chris-Muenchs-Mac-Book-Pro:rails_projects cmuench$ ssh chrismuench@example.com echo \$PATH
Password:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

the git stuff is in:

```
/usr/local/git/bin (Defined in:  /etc/paths.d/git)
```

How can I get this in the system wide path for all users without having to modify ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: Which OS runs on example.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-upload-pack: command not found, how to fix this correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly)

Comment: There is a great answer over here: [Question 225291][1], and in specific this answer: [crewburn's answer][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6495787/870975

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up symlinking the git commands in to /bin

Comment: Not a workable solution for those without write access to /bin.

Answer (score 3):

from client aspect of view

```
ssh clone -u /usr/local/git/bin/git-upload-pack <repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the system wide /etc/profile

Comment: What command would I do? export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH?

Comment: That didn't seem to do it... my path is still :/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin