# Gitosis has been set up, but now cloning asks for "git-upload-pack" password?

Tags: git, gitosis

I have set up the Gitosis as explained here: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitosis

However, now that I run: `git.exe clone ssh://rfactor@192.168.3.3:gitosis-admin.git asd`

I get a prompt from plink.exe (I'm on Windows) asking for "git-upload-pack"'s password. What's that?

Comment: 1.7.2.5 on the server and locally 1.7.7.1.

Comment: Any reason for you to chose the obsolete authorization layer gitosis, instead of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)? And what is the exact error message? Is it a bit like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it works when I run: `git.exe clone rfactor@192.168.3.3:gitosis-admin.git asd`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use key-based ssh logins, and run `peageant` from the putty suite. Then you add your private key to the agent (every time you start a windows session), and the putty tools won't ask for the password again.