# sh: git-upload-pack: command not found

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, sh

I know there is already a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly), but it seems that the solutions proposed do not work for me...

My colleague has created a repository `/git/work` under his account. On my remote machine, I can do the following:

```
... > git clone /users/.../HisAccount/git/work
Initialized empty Git repository in /import/.../MyAccount/work/.git/
```

But I need to control remotely my machine/account, so I have tried the following on my local machine and got an error:

```
...@ubuntu$ git clone MyAccount@OurDomain:/users/.../HisAccount/git/work
Cloning into work...
MyAccount@OurDomain's password: 
sh: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

On my both local and remote machines, I can see `/usr/bin/git-upload-pack`. The `path` on my local machine is `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`; and the `path` on my remote machine is `/users/.../MyAccount/bin/ubuntu /users/.../MyAccount/bin /user/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/hosts /usr/ucb /usr/openwin/bin .`

On my local machine, I have also tried this:

```
... > git clone -u /usr/bin/git-upload-pack MyAccount@OurDomain:/users/.../HisAccount/git/work
Cloning into work...
MyAccount@OurDomain's password: 
sh: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack: No such file or directory
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

By the way, I don't really know where are `.bashrc` (for Bash), `.zshenv` (for Zsh) or `.cshrc` (for tcsh)...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the $PATH`, as set in your "`.bashrc`(for Bash),`.zshenv`(for Zsh),`.cshrc` (for tcsh)"
(depending on the [current shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-what-shell-im-using.html) you are running)

One of those files should be in your `$HOME` (homedir).

From the comments, the OP confirms that

- `/usr/bin/git-upload-pack: No such file or directory` means that the PATh (which is correct) actually doesn't include the `git-upload-pack` script. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly/550145#550145) suggests to symlink to it.
- that  `git-upload-pack` script is called on the remote side, as the OP confirms:

> It turns out that the remote machine has problem... I have tested with another machine, and it works.

Comment: On the remote machine, none of these 3 files exists (the shell is tcsh); On the local machine, there is `.bashrc`, but I have not found `path` in it...

Comment: @SoftTimur those files don't have to always exist. They are created by the user only if he/she want to modify some environment variable in his/her shell session.

Comment: So, should I add a `.cshrc` on my remote machine and change `$PATH`? But its current `$PATH` does conclude `usr/bin`...

Comment: @SoftTimur: except that path doesn't help: `/usr/bin/git-upload-pack: No such file or directory`. You need to check on the Git installation.

Comment: I need to check git installation on my local machine or remote machine?

Comment: @SoftTimur: on the remote. Once you have found where git is installed, you can symlink to it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/550145/6309)

Comment: it turns out that the remote machine has problem... I have tested with another machine, and it works... thank you... I am going to delete the question soon...

Comment: @SoftTimur don't delete it! It will help others

Comment: @SoftTimur I have included your conclusions in the answer for more visibility.