# An internal Exception occurred during push: cannot store objects

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Hello I am new to Git and trying to setup server part and client part.
On a Server side I have ssh access and Git version 1.5 
On a Client side I have eclipse with eGit.

I created git repo on a server side via usual means: git init and added simple html file. 
Using eGit I checkout the repo and everything seems to be going well. I made changes on a client side, committed it and decided to push back to the server.

Now I have all permissions set but still get following error:
[image]

I don't know how to fix it and error message doesn't provide much details.
Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of eGit you are using? If you are using old one, try using latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved my issue following way:

1) I changed configuration for remote fetch and pull from **sftp** to **ssh**

2) Once I did step 1. I got different error:

[image]
When I tried to push changes from Terminal I got following:

> > > git push origin
> > >       Password:
> > >       bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
> > >       fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

3) Found answer to the above error: [git-upload-pack: command not found, how to fix this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly)

4) On my old server path to the git is: "/usr/local/git/bin" So I added it to .bashrc file.

Once I done that, everything started to work:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me, on Windows eclipse, I had an error like this:

```
An internal Exception occurred during push: github.com/***/***/service=git-receive-pack not found
```

I just reconfigured the eclipse and added my github account information and store it. Then it worked. Team->Remove->Configure push to upstream->URI, Change->Add authentication details

Answer (score 0):

The possible issues are:
1. The source code might not be committed in the first place. Please try committing and see.
2. There is some issue with github authentication. Please re authenticate the credentials and try using: Team->Remove->Configure push to upstream->URI, Change->Add authentication