# After moving a remote git repository, I no longer can fetch from it

Tags: git

I switched servers, so I simply rsynced the remote git repository to which I was pushing and pulling changes from over to new server. Now I tried to fetch from it and am getting error:

```
ssh://user@domain.com:1234/home/user/gitrepos/project.git: 
cannot execute: git-upload-pack '/home/user/gitrepos/project.git'
```

What could be causing this problem? How can I troubleshoot?

P.S. domain and ports, along with file repo dir location are all correct.

Comment: Does `git-upload-pack` on the remote server exist? does your `user` account have privileges to execute it?

Comment: @sarnold I didn't realize git was not installed on the new server. That fixed the issue. If you'd like create an answer so that I can mark you. Thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: You also need to make sure `git-upload-pack` is on the path from a non-login shell, which isn't always true even when it is installed. See this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `git` on a remote server, the remote peer also needs `git` installed. (It's a bit like `rsync` -- having software on the remote endpoint allows for computing details on the remote peer to avoid needless network traffic.)

So, be sure that a fully-functional `git` is installed on the remote peer, the commands are located on the `PATH` when you log in via `ssh` normally [as georgebrock points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957306/after-moving-a-remote-git-repository-i-no-longer-can-fetch-from-it#comment14309935_10957306), and your user account has privileges to execute the commands (in case your login shell is confined with a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)).