# git-upload-pack: command not found

Tags: git, bash, shell, command-line

I've read this answer about eight-five times, but there's something I'm not understanding correctly:

[git-upload-pack: command not found, how to fix this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly)

When I try to clone a repository on my server, I get the following:

```
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
```

But when I clone by giving clone the `-u /usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack` option, all works well.

I guess this makes sense, since that's the position of the git-upload-pack on my server.

The top answer suggests my .bashrc file on server needs to be updated to reflect this, as the result of `ssh you@remotemachine echo \$PATH` does not return `/usr/local/bin`. (It returns `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`).

But when I look at my .bashrc file, it contains:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

So now I'm confused.

What do I need to do to avoid using the `-u /usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack` option every time? Why does `ssh you@remotemachine echo \$PATH` not return `/usr/local/bin`? Is this something to do with login and non-login shells?

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this part of the `bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is connected to this issue:

https://serverfault.com/questions/130834/svnssh-getting-bash-to-load-my-path-over-ssh

Ssh is not loading your environment by default when sending a command without going to interactive mode.

good solution is the one with .ssh/environment file:

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config add:

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

Then just create .ssh/ directory and dump envronment to .ssh/enviroment:

```
cd ~/
mkdir .ssh
env > .ssh/environment
```

Restart SSH

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Now when you do this from your local machine:

```
ssh you@server.com  "which git-upload-pack"
```

you s'd get

```
/usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack
```

and git clone s'd work.

Comment: I was trying to access a git repo on my mac using ssh. I had to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add "PermitUserEnvironment yes" and then restarted the sshd thru System preferences->Sharing->Remove Login. I didn't have to create the .ssh/environment file

Comment: Looks like a typo in the restart command. Shouldn't it be: /etc/init.d/ssh restart ?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is to do with login and non-login shells. The `.bashrc` file only gets loaded in non-login shells. You can use `.bash_profile` for login shells. Just add the same modification to your `PATH` in the `.bash_profile` file and you should be good.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You may find [this is an interesting article on the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile, and login and non-login shells.](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense – but doesn't seem to work for me. Both my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` contain the code `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`, but this isn't doing the trick.

`ssh you@remotemachine echo \$PATH` still returns `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

Possible reasons? (Guesses.)

1. I'm on a Media Temple server and there's a .bash_mt_profile file. (But I added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` for good measure and it didn't seem to work.)

2. I'm logged in as root.

3. I'm not using bash (but when I log in, it says I can edit my `.bash_profile` to remove system messages.

Comment: @Chris: Out of interest, does your `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc` file have the perms set to 644, is owned by the correct user, and has no executable bit set?

The file is sourced, not executed, but must be owned by the user who is attempting the source and must have 644 (or greater) perms.

If it keeps failing for you after checking these, you could always try adding the PATH change to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/*` (depending on your distro).

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, perms are 644. I reset them anyway. It didn't work. Added a file called git.sh to `/etc/profile.d/` with the code `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (is that the correct thing to do?) and that hasn't worked either. I can only assume I've not done something blindingly obvious.

Comment: Yeah, that is the right code. Only thing I can think of is that maybe the `git.sh` file isn't executable, try `chmod +x` to see if that makes a difference?

Other than that, it sounds like the MT servers are perhaps hardcoding the `PATH` variable at a lower level somewhere?

Comment: I had a similar issue, where I didn't have root access. So for me this answer is more superior than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue in my case by logging into the remote machine, a Ubuntu box, and doing `sudo apt-get install git`.  Not sure if this is overkill or not, but solved the problem for me instantly.

Comment: At first I thought `git-upload-pack` was just a missing dependency in the client environment, but it wasn't missing. Then this answer helped me realize that the "command not found" error was actually referring to the *remote environment* (in my case, a Raspberry Pi connected to the LAN), which didn't have Git installed.

Answer (score 2):

**My solution for this problem**

1. Check path for the git-upload-pack on your remote machine:

   ```
   ssh yourname@IP-addressORdomain 'which git-upload-pack'
   ```

If it gives a path - copy it (without `git-upload-pack` and trailing slash. Examples: `/usr/bin`, `/home/yourname/bin`, `/whatever/gituploadpack/path`, etc.).

1. Check your PATH on the remote machine during login shell:

   ```
   ssh yourname@IP-addressORdomain 'echo $PATH'
   ```

There is no such a path (`/whatever/gituploadpack/path`), is not it? Good!

1. Login to your remote machine:

   ```
   ssh yourname@IP-addressORdomain
   ```
2. Open .bashrc_profile:

   ```
   nano /home/yourname/.bashrc_profile
   ```
3. Find these lines if any:

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        ~/.bashrc
   fi
   ```

...and change them for:

```
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        source ~/.bashrc
    fi
```

1. Open .bashrc:

   ```
   nano /home/yourname/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add these 4 lines:

   ```
   if [ -d "/whatever/gituploadpack/path" ] ; then
     PATH="$PATH:/whatever/gituploadpack/path"
   fi
   export PATH
   ```
3. Exit the remote machine:

   ```
   exit
   ```
4. Check your PATH on the remote machine during login shell:

   ```
   ssh yourname@IP-addressORdomain 'echo $PATH'
   ```

Do you see `/whatever/gituploadpack/path`? Congrats!

Note now you've solved not only `git-upload-pack` problem but also `git-receive-pack` and other executables on your `/whatever/gituploadpack/path`!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following errors:

`git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11`

When I was doing git pull, I would get

`fatal: https://github.com/.../../info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

I am guessing it had to do with my previous invalid github credentials in the keychain.

- Opened keychain access tool using Command space
- searched for github in the keychain access tool
- removed all the entries related to github (since I no longer needed it)
- followed the setup git password caching section again [setup git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
- it worked

Incase any of the above answers does not help.