# Git pushing to cpanel server - git-receive-pack: command not found

Tags: git

I am attempting to setup a GIT environment to achieve the following:

1. Repo where my code is stored (setup and working using Gitorious)
2. A production and staging environment on a server (server setup)
3. Local repo on my computer (working)

My production and staging server is a cpanel server and I followed this guys [suggestions](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2012/11/20/do-yourself-a-favor-set-up-a-staging-server/)  set it up.

All seems fine however I keep getting the following error:

stdin: is not a tty
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The first line I know is just a bash thing to be ignored. The second issue I have followed the suggestions in this post: [Pushing and existing project into bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435912/pushing-and-existing-project-into-bare-repo) and I am stumped.

1. What is a "git-receive-pack"
2. Where is it located?
3. If it is not located anywhere, how do I get my hands on it?

If I run ssh user@0.0.0.0 which git-receive-pack, this returns: "no git-receive-pack in ... ", and when I run the same command from shell, I get the same answer.

Do I grep the server to find the file??

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question on SO helped me to solve this problem: [Git on godaddy - git-upload-pack not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345497/git-on-godaddy-git-upload-pack-not-found)

Essentially I added the following to my git file:

```
url = root@server.location.com:/home/folder/git/staging.git
receivepack = /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git-receive-pack
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

To make this process smoother I additionally added my computers SSH key to the server so I no longer need to enter a password.