# Deploying a Symfony2 project to cPanel server using Git

Tags: php, git, symfony, deployment, cpanel

I have a Symfony project, I'm using Git for version control. Now I need to deploy it using cPanel.

Can I configure my cPanel Server to be able to push directly from a git repository?

Comment: As stated [here](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/installing-git.294411/), it's not recommended you use Git on cPanel as it can break features of cPanel. For PHP, if you want to deploy to cPanel on Apache you can follow [this guide](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/PHP+Options).
This isn't a solution for you as there may be a way to build from Git to auto deploy to cPanel, but I don't know of it.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792221/git-pushing-to-cpanel-server-git-receive-pack-command-not-found