# GitLab "git-receive-pack not found"

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I tried to configure **VPS** with **GitLab** that I installed from **Digital Ocean**.

Everything works fine excepts from git pushing and pulling. when I use this command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

the result that I'm getting is:

```
git@(ipAddress)'s password: [my password]
sh: 1: git-receive-pack: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question :

In the working directory follow the command

> git remote # this will tell you the remote repo

then

> git remote rm branch

Then add your current repo like

> git remote add origin `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: I'm getting this error on the second command: 
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.branch'

Comment: That mean remote doesn`t exists. Please check the correct name

Comment: Did what you suggested to do, the result was the same (the output is exactly the same as it was before)

Comment: Tried this also git remote set-url website abc@***.com:path/to/repo

Comment: Yes I did, same result.

Comment: Are you using different machine to connect with .? I think this is happen because of ssh issue

Comment: Yes, is there any option to analyze if this it's really a ssh issue?

Comment: ok .. backup old keys and generate new keys using ssh-keygen and copy public keys into digital ocean accounts . This is ok i think let`s try that let me know

Comment: omnibus doesn't install git. Make sure git is installed on your server. And follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128464/git-upload-pack-command-not-found