# git Setup for Mac OS X Terminal (recieve-pack-not-found)

Tags: git, command-line, terminal, installation

I've noticed that this is a hot topic, so apologies for adding to the flood. It looks like I'm having the same issue as everyone (see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594474/git-recieve-pack-not-found) thread). I am also following the [official git setup guide](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)

On a push, I get the fatal error recieve-pack-not-found.

I assume it is the same $PATH related issue that everyone else is having. The advice in other threads proposes testing the $PATH using the line

```
ssh you@remotemachine echo \$PATH
```

I have no idea what to substitute "you" & "remotemachine" with. I couldn't believe no one else had asked in the other threads, but that just speaks to my prior knowledge I suppose.

I assume "you" = my git Username
I thought "remotemachine" would be my URL (https://github.com/username)

Can someone point me back in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was literally staring me in the face. When you enter your username terminal asks for the password for "username@github.com".

Slapping forehead for thinking that github.com/me was on it's own server...