# msysgit - Edit remote PATH for ssh

Tags: git, bash, ssh, msysgit

In mysysgit when I do ssh user@machine.com echo \$PATH I am missing a few items in my PATH in order to work with git.  Specifically git-upload-pack.  I saw this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/225315/333890) which confirmed my problem, but I have been unable to figure out how to edit the PATH such that ssh user@machine.com echo \$PATH reflects the correct path to my missing commands.

So, the question, how do I edit the PATH variable for my remote connections?

I have tried created a .bashrc in my $HOME of my git-bash and I've tried looking around in various other places, but can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you create your `.bashrc` in your remote system and not on your current local machine.

You can add something like this on it:

```
PATH=/path/to/git/bin/dir:$PATH
export PATH # optional
```

Try placing it in `.profile` as well if it doesn't work with `.bashrc`.

Comment: Tried placing it in .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile in /home/$USER all with no luck.

Comment: @Adam And it's in your remote system? I think your it depends on the remote system shell you're running. Are you sure it's bash?

Comment: ssh <my machine> echo \$SHELL shows zsh, I added it to .zshrc as well without any luck

Comment: only /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.  I needed to put it in .zshenv not .zshrc