# Cannot Clone EGit Repo on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, adt, git-clone

everyone.  I've been struggling with this for a long time now.  So I started an Android application using the Android Development Tools (ADT) on my computer and now I want to move this project into a repository on my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 server, so I can work on it with a friend without constantly overwriting one another.  I zipped the project on my computer, extracted and imported it on the server (using Eclipse on both ends) and created a git repository on the server by right clicking and going to `Team -> Share Project`

Now when I try to clone it from my (Windows) computer, I can't seem to connect properly no matter what protocol I use, be it git, SSH, FTP or HTTP.  I want to try HTTP since it's the easiest (or am I totally wrong?)

The server has a static IP address, namely 192.168.1.42 (it also has a WAN address which I'll give my friend once this gets sorted out), and the project, along with the .git folder inside it, are under var/www/git/Eclipse Workspace/Musica

I can browse to that folder on Chrome from my computer, and to the hidden .git folder as well, but whenever I try to connect on Eclipse it says:

> [address]/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found

And I can't seem to get around that.  I've also tried using SSH, but the first time I connect it asks me to add a key, then fails loading the files, and every attempt thereafter fails to connect in the first place.  FTP isn't cooperating either, nor is git nor file.

I'm out of ideas.  I would really appreciate any guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly

Comment: @racraman I followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6495787/2333689) but I still get the same errors.  I'm not sure how to edit the .bashrc