# Github git-upload-pack command not found. could not find remote repositroy

Tags: git, github

To start with, I should say I am not very knowledgeable about git. I have repo that I have been pushing to and using gh-pages to deploy to github pages. Everything has been working just fine. 
Now all of a sudden, I start getting this error

```
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but only when using gh-pages to try to deploy my app to github pages. I can still push and pull without any issue. I didn't change the name or anything about the repository, so I am not sure why all of a sudden this has started to become an issue. I tried to use this [git-upload-pack: command not found, when cloning remote Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-when-cloning-remote-git-repo), but like I said I'm not very knowledgeable about git and it just confused me.

If it makes a difference I'm using the git shell on windows 10

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has this issue I solved it by adding 
`GitHub/PortableGit_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/mingw32/bin` to my PATH variable