# gh-pages d- build: failed at deploy script

Tags: git, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a react app to github.
I followed some simple tutorials pretty much to the letter, but always get stuck on this screen.
Found some old threads that recommended to remove and re-add the remote origin, but that did not seem to help.

[CMD Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXVes.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-upload-pack: command not found, when cloning remote Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-when-cloning-remote-git-repo)

Comment: Did you build your project before deploying?

Answer (score 2):

Met a similar challenge recently, and not many answers nail it.
Most blogs will show you how to about it from a `create-react-app` concept, but outside that you are more less on your own.

Here is a quick one:

1. First, make sure you understand the commands that you are running.
   Needless to say, i also error-ed at first, so...
   `gh-pages -d build` literally means you want to "publish your page" 
   based on a folder "build/". That's what the `-d` or --dir`means. 
   read more here [install and use gh-pages-cli][1]. So start by either 
   making sure you have the folder "build/" or better point it to where 
   the files you want to bundle are located in your project.

   [Have a look at scripts in my package.json file][2] (incase you are 
   curious, the`-b`` means the branch you want to "publish" from).
2. If the above does not solve your issue, just like for me, because the command [published successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ON9.png) but i still kept getting a `404 Error` when i tried accessing the page on `https://<my-username>/github.io/<my-repository>/`.

   So here is the alternative i used:

   - Create a new branch `gh-pages` from the branch which has the 
     project version that you want to publish.
   - Run `git push origin gh-pages` to push that branch to your remote repository which is hosted on github.
   - Note that github is configured to publish any project code that you have in this branch - `gh-pages`. Confirm this by clicking the `settings` tab in your repo, and if you navigate down, you'll [see something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY86g.png) under the heading "Github Pages".
   - Some key things to remember: One, your `index.html` (main template) must be within your project root folder directly (not under subfolders). My project root folder was `/fast-React/` so i placed my index page at `/fast-React/index.html`. And second, commit your bundled/build files. In most projects, bundled/build files are added to `.gitignore` so you better commit them, at least within this `gh-pages` branch. [Here is why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvXw.png) - they need to be fetched by your `<script>` tag, most likely.

See this test project as [published here](https://mwamitovi.github.io/fast-React/). Good luck.